# ı wanna post two id from .html to views

Tags: python, django, url

html file ı wanna take two id to views.py can ı get it ?

```
path('yorum_sil/<int:id>',views.yorum_sil,name="yorum_sil")
```

I want to do this code like the below

```
path('yorum_sil/<int:comment_id> and <int:post_id>',views.yorum_sil,name="yorum_sil")
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: path('yorum_sil/<int:comment_id> and <int:post_id>',views.yorum_sil)  
ı wrote and here just for u can understand but ı think usage is not like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is possible, although you should not use spaces like that. You can for example use a slash like:

```
path('yorum_sil/<int:comment_id>/<int:post_id>',views.yorum_sil,name="yorum_sil")
```

Your view function (here `yorum_sil`) then of course needs to accept the two parameters, like:

```
# app/views.py

def yorum_sil(request, comment_id, post_id):
    # ...
    return ...
```

and if you perform a reverse lookup, you need to pass the two parameters. For example in a template like:

```
<a href="{% url 'yorum_sil' comment_id=14 post_id=25 %}">some_link</a>
```

If I translated *yorum sil* correctly it means *delete comments*, note that typically GET requests should *not* have side effects. In order to delete/create/... an entity, you should use a POST request.

Comment: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'   ım getting this error when program comes to the return reverse function and ı wrote reverse function like 
return reverse("detay",kwargs={"id":comment_id})

Comment: @İsaGİRİŞKEN: in that specific view, you should write `return redirect("detay", id=comment_id)`. But this has nothing to do with this URL, every view should return a HTTP response, not a string.

Comment: @İsaGİRİŞKEN: don't perform a `redirect(reverse(..))`, you can use `redirect('view_name', some_parameter=some_value)`, this is horter, more elegant, and safer.